# Mobile Safari and CSS Transitions of Multiple Elements are Lagging

Tags: jquery, css, mobile-safari, css-transitions

I have a website in which I perform transitions of multiple `DIVs` with image backgrounds, from one CSS class to another (using jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass`).

```
.class1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}

.class2 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 80px;
}

.fade {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.6s linear, -webkit-transform 5s linear, width 5s linear, height 5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.6s linear, background-size 5s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.6s linear, background-size 5s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.6s linear, background-size 5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear, background-size 5s linear;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

All `DIVs` are initialized (when page is loaded) with the `fade` class.

Now, when animating one `DIV`, on Mobile Safari, everything works smoothly.
However, when animating more than one element **simultaneously**, Mobile Safari *lags horribly*.
Obviously, this works just fine on regular browsers such as Chrome.

Methods I've tried for resolving this:

- Using `translate3d` and `scale3d` CSS properties
- Using jQuery's `animate`
- Using jQueryUI's `switchClass`
- Using `IMG` tags instead of `DIV` with background images

Any help will be much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've managed to find out what was causing this issue:
The `fade` class is applied to many inner DIVs within the main DIVs, and I needed that effect only for certain transitions, which do not include this resize transition (for this, I have another CSS class).

So, right before applying the transition, I call `removeClass('fade')`, and when ending the transition, I add it once again.